# Basicbinding ServiceSecurityContext Null

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a service that uses wsHttpBinding security mode="Message" message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" .

When a client calls the service, on the service side I can use  ServiceSecurityContext context = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext; in order to get the callers credentials.

However, now I need a Java client to call this service.  Apparently, wsHttpBinding does not interop easily w/Java (I thought that was the whole point of services).  So I need to change the binding to basicHttpBinding to get the interop, but now OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext returns null.

I have tried mutliple combinations from posts I have seen, but all the post are slightly different and did not work for me.

I am hoping that someone smarter than I can resolve this once and for all.

Here are the requirements:
1.)Basicbinding needs to be used.
2.)OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext needs to be populated automatically and retrieved on server side like it is with wsHttpBinding.

Here are the basic bindings I used among others..

```
    <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBasicBinding"
    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
    </security>
    </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you actually need user credentials, and not just the user name? Also, have you tried this walkthrough? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx

Comment: I actually don't need credentials.  The name is all that is really needed.  However, I was hoping to make this work just by changing the config file.  The code has this statement "ServiceSecurityContext context = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext;".  Which returns null.  The programmer didn't check for null before this statement-"string UserName = context.WindowsIdentity.Name;"  And so the code blows up because "context" is null.  I will take a look at your link now.  Thanks!

Comment: The example I think will work.  However, in the example, on the client side, the code explicitly sets the credentials in the proxy ie "myService.Credentials =                       System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;"  I was hoping to have the credentials autmatically sent (no explicit statement in client side code) like it is when I use the WShttpbinding.

Comment: Again this is a Java side client.  We are trying to avoid having to make changes to it.  And unfortunately I don't know Java so it is difficult for me at this point to make changes to that side of the code.  If I have to so be it but I was hoping someone out there would have a definitive answer as to whether I can do what I need to do withou makeing code changes.